# Change only one bit in a file

Tags: dd, hashsum

I have to test a hash function and I want to change only a single bit of a specific file.

I tried with the dd command. That works, but I can only change a whole byte and not just a bit.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/file.bin bs=1 seek=10 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

I also tried the sed command with a regex, but as I don't know the content of the file, I can't just change an "a" to a "b".

Does anyone know a command for doing this?

Comment: If you can find a lower case character (ascii, or single byte utf8) and convert to upper case, or visa versa. Then this is a 1 bit change. This is not a very good solution hence just a comment.

Comment: Yes it's probably the best option, but can I change only the first occurence ? And I can get a result in case of success/not found ? Maybe it's possible with a XOR mask on the file directly ?

Comment: How do you determine which bit to change? Is your goal to _toggle a bit at a specific offset_? And do you change 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, or (say) do you always set it to 1? Finally: What kind of data does the file contain? Could it be "binary", i.e. including null bytes?

Comment: Ideally, toggle a random or fixed bit is excellent, but if I can already force a bit to zero or one is also good for me. And yes it's a binary file

Comment: This is a bit rubbish as well, it may give you some ideas, it extract character 5 of `hello world` and adds one to it, it does not as yet put it back. `printf '%b\n' $(printf '\%03o' $(expr $(printf "%d\n" \'$(echo hello world | dd if=/dev/stdin of=/dev/stdout bs=1 count=1 skip=4 2>/dev/null)) + 1))` I think that if I were doing it, then I would do it in python or another general purpose language.

Comment: I'd just write a program to read the byte containing the selected bit position, construct a byte differing in just the one bit, and write it out. Since file length does not change, you only need to read and write that one byte.

Comment: Your question is also the answer to a related question, since I came here to find out how to change a single byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file may contain nulls, text-oriented filters like `sed` are going to fail. But you can use a programming language that can handle nulls, like `perl` or `python`. Here's a solution for Python 3. It's a few lines longer than strictly necessary, for readability.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Toggle the bit at the specified offset.
Syntax: <cmdname> filename bit-offset"""

import sys
fname = sys.argv[1]
# Convert bit offset to bytes + leftover bits
bitpos = int(sys.argv[2])
nbytes, nbits = divmod(bitpos, 8)

# Open in read+write, binary mode; read 1 byte 
fp = open(fname, "r+b")
fp.seek(nbytes, 0)
c = fp.read(1)

# Toggle bit at byte position `nbits`
toggled = bytes( [ ord(c)^(1<<nbits) ] ) 
# print(toggled) # diagnostic output

# Back up one byte, write out the modified byte
fp.seek(-1, 1)  # or absolute: fp.seek(nbytes, 0)
fp.write(toggled)
fp.close()
```

Save it in a file (e.g., `bitflip`), make it executable, and run it with the filename to modify and the offset *in bits*. Note that it modifies the file in place. Run it twice with the same offset and you'll get your file restored.

Comment: Works like a charm, and it's smart

Comment: This does not work if running in Python2 (Author should use /usr/bin/env python3 for clarity!  Create file with 00000 (ascii). Change bit 2. The output should only change one character but changes 4. Make sure to run in Python 3 and not Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the shebang. (The text did already say that the solution is "for Python 3", but this is better.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a single command.
Here's a simple script, save it as "`flipbit`":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Arguments:   byte (starting from 0),  bit (0-7),  filename (otherwise stdin)
$byte = shift(@ARGV);
$bit = shift(@ARGV);
undef $/; 
$file=<>; 
substr($file,$byte,1) = substr($file,$byte,1) ^ chr(1<<$bit); 
print $file;
```

test:

```
$ echo abb | ~/bin/flip-bit.pl 2 0 | od -xa
0000000      6261    0a63                                                
       a   b   c  nl
```

this flipped the low-order bit (0) of the third character, changing the 'b' to 'c'.

As a single line command:

```
perl -e '$byte=shift(@ARGV);$bit=shift(@ARGV);undef $/; $file=<>; substr($file,$byte,1) = substr($file,$byte,1) ^ chr(1<<$bit); print $file'
```

Comment: Hint: You need to redirect `stdout` into a file to have the result saved. Example: `perl flipbit.pl 1000000 1 data.tgz > data_corrupt.tgz`

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a solution with `xxd` and `dd`.

```
a=$(xxd -b -l 1 -seek 3 -p a.bin);b=1;echo -e "\x$((${a}^${b}))" | dd of=a.bin bs=1 seek=3 count=1 conv=notrunc

hexdump a.bin     v
0000000 61 39 73 36 36 64 66 38 61 39 73 64 35 36 66 35
0000010 37 61 73 64 37 66 74 75 61 67 73 0a 61 73 64 66

hexdump b.bin     v
0000000 61 39 73 37 36 64 66 38 61 39 73 64 35 36 66 35
0000010 37 61 73 64 37 66 74 75 61 67 73 0a 61 73 64 66
```

But this is ugly.

Comment: I got a bash error for a byte with leading '0' so I changed the XOR part to `echo -e "\x$((${a#0}^${b}))"`

Comment: Sorry, it should be a `0x${a}`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `dd`, here is an abomination that will do the trick by flipping the highest bit in the given byte. Adjust the settings for the `tr` command to change the selected bit.

```
# Preparation
finger > original.txt
BYTE=3

# Here we go...
dd if=original.txt bs=1c 2>/dev/null | ( dd bs=1c count=$((BYTE-1)) ; dd bs=1c count=1 | tr '\000-\377' '\200-\377\000-\177' ; dd bs=1c ) 2>/dev/null > flipped.txt

# Demonstrate the difference (byte 3: 67 → e7)
hexdump -C original.txt | head -1
00000000  4c 6f 67 69 6e 20 20 20  20 20 4e 61 6d 65 20 20  |Login     Name  |    
hexdump -C flipped.txt | head -1
00000000  4c 6f e7 69 6e 20 20 20  20 20 4e 61 6d 65 20 20  |Lo.in     Name  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `head`, `tail`, `xxd`. Example below flips least significant bit in last byte of *file.bin*.

```
head -c -1 file.bin > flipped.bin
LAST=`tail -c 1 file.bin | xxd -ps`
printf "%02X" $(( $((16#$LAST)) ^ 1 )) | xxd -r -ps >> flipped.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two `perl` one-liners. The first changes the file `bar` in-place:

```
perl -p -0777 -i -e 'substr($_,2,1)^=chr(1<<5)' bar
```

The second reads file `foo` and writes `bar`

```
perl -p -0777 -e 'substr($_,2,1)^=chr(1<<5)' < foo > bar
```

To adapt to your application: the 2 selects which byte: 0..file_length-1, i.e. 2 is the 3rd byte. The 5 selects which bit to flip: 0-7, i.e 5 is the 6th bit.  This will only work for files that fit in memory.

## Explanation

`-p` iterate through the file, print after each iteration
`-0777` read the whole file into memory on each iteration (so there will only be one iteration)
`-e` run the following perl code inside the loop
`substr` select a single character in the file starting at index 2
`^=chr` XOR that character with 1 shifted 5 times i.e. 2^5

This answer is a simplified version of [toddkaufmann's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196261/28971)